# If I include 2 files in a main file, can I make functions from 1st incuded file available in 2nd

Tags: python

I have a main .py file.

In this I import 2 other files.
The first is a module containing a series of debug functions called debug.py.
The second just contains a class definition.

I want my debug functions to be available to be called from within the class.

I do not want to import debug.py in my class file, as it has configurable options which I do not want to have to set multiple times across the program.

Is this possible, and how would I do it?

I include below a very simplified example of my code.

main.py:

```
import debug
from class import CLASS

debug.debug_messages_enabled = True

my_object = CLASS()
```

debug.py:

```
debug_messages_enabled = False

def log (message):
    if debug_messages_enabled:
        output = ""
        output += "[LOG]: " 
        output += message
        print output
```

class.py:

```
class CLASS (object):
    def __init__ ():
        #I want to be able to access debug.log here
```

Comment: include is not a keyword for python

Comment: You're right, my bad. I'm very new to the language. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `debug.py` in your class file.

The fact that `main.py` makes a change to one setting in the debug module is not relevant. Your class files is going to contain the debug statements, make the debug calls, etc.

The decision to print/not print will be made based on that setting. The setting (`debug_messages_enabled`) will be changed by `main.py`, but that doesn't matter to `class.py`.

class.py:

```
from debug import log

class CLASS (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        log("A long thick section of trimmed, unhewn timber.")
        self.foo = 1
```